# Close menu when click detected outside

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

I'm trying to close a menu when the user clicks outside of the element. I have tried many solutions from Stack overflow but none of them work for me. The user should be able to click on the menu button (3 dots), which then shows the menu. Then if they click outside of this, it should close each time.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lzeukhcj/1/

Here is my code and what I have tried:

**Javascript**

```
  const dots = document.querySelector(".dot-wrap");
  const popup = document.querySelector(".popup");

  dots.onclick = () => {
    popup.style.display = "block";
  }

  document.onclick = (event) => {
    let isClickInside = popup.contains(event.target);

    if (!isClickInside) {
      console.log("outside box");
      popup.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
```

**SCSS**

```
.tweet-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #f1f1f1;
}

.tweet-container-right {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.tweet-header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 100;
}

.icon-container {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.user-info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
 

  .tweet-name {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    color: #0f1419;
  }

  .tweet-username {
    font-size:15px;
    
    color: #526470;
  }

  .middle-dot{
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
  }

  .time {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #526470;
  }
}

.tweet-text {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.verified-tick{
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.dots-popup-container {
  position: relative;

  .dots {
    width: 18px;
    fill: red;
  }

  .popup {
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    display: none;
    /*height: 0px;*/
    transition: 2s ease;
    box-shadow: 0 0.5px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding-top: 14px;

    .popup-option {
      display: flex;
      margin-bottom: 20px;

      p {
        color: #526470;
      }
      .popup-icon {
        width: 20px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        fill: #526470;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
 

  <div class="tweet-container-right">
    <div class="tweet-header">
      <div class="user-info">
        <h3 class="tweet-name">Title </h3>
        
 
        <span class="middle-dot">&#183;</span>
        <p class="time">2d</p>
      </div>

      <div class="dots-popup-container">

        <div class="dot-wrap">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-1xvli5t r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1hdv0qi dots">
            <g>
              <circle cx="5" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
              <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
              <circle cx="19" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
            </g>
          </svg>
        </div>






        <div class="popup">
          <div class="popup-option">

            <div>
              <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="popup-icon">
                <g>
                  <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z"></path>
                  <path d="M12 13.415c1.892 0 3.633.95 4.656 2.544.224.348.123.81-.226 1.035-.348.226-.812.124-1.036-.226-.747-1.162-2.016-1.855-3.395-1.855s-2.648.693-3.396 1.854c-.224.35-.688.45-1.036.225-.35-.224-.45-.688-.226-1.036 1.025-1.594 2.766-2.545 4.658-2.545zm4.216-3.957c0 .816-.662 1.478-1.478 1.478s-1.478-.66-1.478-1.478c0-.817.662-1.478 1.478-1.478s1.478.66 1.478 1.478zm-5.476 0c0 .816-.662 1.478-1.478 1.478s-1.478-.66-1.478-1.478c0-.817.662-1.478 1.478-1.478.817 0 1.478.66 1.478 1.478z"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <p>Not interested in this tweet</p>
          </div>

          <div class="popup-option">
            <div>
              <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="popup-icon">
                <g>
                  <path d="M20.083 6.173l2.323 2.323c.293.293.768.293 1.06 0s.294-.768 0-1.06l-2.32-2.326 2.322-2.323c.293-.294.293-.77 0-1.062s-.768-.293-1.06 0L20.082 4.05 17.76 1.73c-.293-.293-.768-.293-1.06 0-.147.146-.22.338-.22.53s.072.384.22.53l2.32 2.32-2.32 2.325c-.147.146-.22.338-.22.53s.072.384.22.53c.292.293.767.293 1.06 0l2.323-2.32zM8.417 11.816c1.355 0 2.872-.15 3.84-1.256.813-.93 1.077-2.367.806-4.392-.38-2.826-2.116-4.513-4.645-4.513-2.53 0-4.267 1.687-4.646 4.513-.273 2.025-.01 3.462.805 4.393.968 1.108 2.485 1.257 3.84 1.257zm-3.16-5.448c.16-1.2.786-3.212 3.16-3.212 2.373 0 2.998 2.013 3.16 3.212.207 1.55.056 2.627-.45 3.205-.455.52-1.266.743-2.71.743s-2.256-.223-2.71-.743c-.507-.578-.658-1.656-.45-3.205zm11.44 12.867c-.88-3.525-4.283-5.988-8.28-5.988-3.998 0-7.403 2.463-8.28 5.988-.172.693-.03 1.4.395 1.94.408.522 1.04.822 1.733.822H14.57c.69 0 1.323-.3 1.73-.82.425-.54.568-1.247.396-1.942zm-1.577 1.018c-.126.16-.316.245-.55.245H2.264c-.235 0-.426-.085-.552-.246-.137-.174-.18-.412-.12-.654.71-2.855 3.517-4.85 6.824-4.85s6.113 1.994 6.824 4.85c.06.24.017.48-.12.655z"></path>
                </g>
              </svg>
            </div>
            <p>Unfollow whoever</p>
          </div>

          <div class="popup-option">
            <div>
              <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="popup-icon">
                <g>
                  <path d="M1.75 22.354c-.192 0-.384-.073-.53-.22-.293-.293-.293-.768 0-1.06L20.395 1.898c.293-.294.768-.294 1.06 0s.294.767 0 1.06L2.28 22.135c-.146.146-.338.22-.53.22zm1.716-5.577c-.134 0-.27-.036-.392-.11-.67-.413-1.07-1.13-1.07-1.917v-5.5c0-1.24 1.01-2.25 2.25-2.25H6.74l7.047-5.588c.225-.18.533-.215.792-.087.258.125.423.387.423.675v3.28c0 .415-.336.75-.75.75s-.75-.335-.75-.75V3.553L7.47 8.338c-.134.104-.298.162-.467.162h-2.75c-.413 0-.75.337-.75.75v5.5c0 .263.134.5.356.64.353.216.462.678.245 1.03-.14.23-.387.357-.64.357zm10.787 5.973c-.166 0-.33-.055-.466-.162l-4.795-3.803c-.325-.258-.38-.73-.122-1.054.258-.322.73-.38 1.054-.12l3.58 2.838v-7.013c0-.414.335-.75.75-.75s.75.336.75.75V22c0 .288-.166.55-.425.675-.104.05-.216.075-.327.075z"></path>
                </g>
              </svg> </div>
            <p>Mute whoever</p>

          </div>
          <div class="popup-option">
            <div>
              <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="popup-icon">
                <g>
                  <path d="M12 1.25C6.072 1.25 1.25 6.072 1.25 12S6.072 22.75 12 22.75 22.75 17.928 22.75 12 17.928 1.25 12 1.25zm0 1.5c2.28 0 4.368.834 5.982 2.207L4.957 17.982C3.584 16.368 2.75 14.282 2.75 12c0-5.1 4.15-9.25 9.25-9.25zm0 18.5c-2.28 0-4.368-.834-5.982-2.207L19.043 6.018c1.373 1.614 2.207 3.7 2.207 5.982 0 5.1-4.15 9.25-9.25 9.25z"></path>
                </g>
              </svg>
            </div>
            <p>Block whoever</p>
          </div>

          <div class="popup-option">
            <div>
              <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="popup-icon">
                <g>
                  <path d="M20.083 6.173l2.323 2.323c.293.293.768.293 1.06 0s.294-.768 0-1.06l-2.32-2.326 2.322-2.323c.293-.294.293-.77 0-1.062s-.768-.293-1.06 0L20.082 4.05 17.76 1.73c-.293-.293-.768-.293-1.06 0-.147.146-.22.338-.22.53s.072.384.22.53l2.32 2.32-2.32 2.325c-.147.146-.22.338-.22.53s.072.384.22.53c.292.293.767.293 1.06 0l2.323-2.32zM8.417 11.816c1.355 0 2.872-.15 3.84-1.256.813-.93 1.077-2.367.806-4.392-.38-2.826-2.116-4.513-4.645-4.513-2.53 0-4.267 1.687-4.646 4.513-.273 2.025-.01 3.462.805 4.393.968 1.108 2.485 1.257 3.84 1.257zm-3.16-5.448c.16-1.2.786-3.212 3.16-3.212 2.373 0 2.998 2.013 3.16 3.212.207 1.55.056 2.627-.45 3.205-.455.52-1.266.743-2.71.743s-2.256-.223-2.71-.743c-.507-.578-.658-1.656-.45-3.205zm11.44 12.867c-.88-3.525-4.283-5.988-8.28-5.988-3.998 0-7.403 2.463-8.28 5.988-.172.693-.03 1.4.395 1.94.408.522 1.04.822 1.733.822H14.57c.69 0 1.323-.3 1.73-.82.425-.54.568-1.247.396-1.942zm-1.577 1.018c-.126.16-.316.245-.55.245H2.264c-.235 0-.426-.085-.552-.246-.137-.174-.18-.412-.12-.654.71-2.855 3.517-4.85 6.824-4.85s6.113 1.994 6.824 4.85c.06.24.017.48-.12.655z"></path>
                </g>
              </svg>
            </div>
            <p>Mark as spoiler</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click the `dots` to open the popup, your document `click` event listener is checking whether the target is a child of the popup. Since the toggle is not, the modal is opened, then closed.

You can fix this by using [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to prevent this `click` event from being captured by the document `click` event listener when the dots are clicked.

Your JS should be:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const dots = document.querySelector(".dot-wrap");
  const popup = document.querySelector(".popup");

  dots.onclick = (e) => {
    popup.style.display = "block";
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  document.onclick = (event) => {
      let isClickInside = popup.contains(event.target);

      if (!isClickInside) {
        console.log("outside box");
        popup.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
}
```

Demo:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const dots = document.querySelector(".dot-wrap");
  const popup = document.querySelector(".popup");

  dots.onclick = (e) => {
    popup.style.display = "block";
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  document.onclick = (event) => {
    let isClickInside = popup.contains(event.target);

    if (!isClickInside) {
      console.log("outside box");
      popup.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* compiled from scss */

.tweet-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #f1f1f1;
}

.tweet-container-right {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.tweet-header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 100;
}

.icon-container {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.user-info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.user-info .tweet-name {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  color: #0f1419;
}

.user-info .tweet-username {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #526470;
}

.user-info .middle-dot {
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.user-info .time {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #526470;
}

.tweet-text {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.verified-tick {
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.dots-popup-container {
  position: relative;
}

.dots-popup-container .dots {
  width: 18px;
  fill: red;
}

.dots-popup-container .popup {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  display: none;
  /*height: 0px;*/
  transition: 2s ease;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-top: 14px;
}

.dots-popup-container .popup .popup-option {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.dots-popup-container .popup .popup-option p {
  color: #526470;
}

.dots-popup-container .popup .popup-option .popup-icon {
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  fill: #526470;
}
```

```html
<div class="tweet-container">
  <div class="tweet-container-right">
    <div class="tweet-header">
      <div class="user-info">
        <h3 class="tweet-name">Title </h3>
        <span class="middle-dot">&#183;</span>
        <p class="time">2d</p>
      </div>
      <div class="dots-popup-container">
        <div class="dot-wrap">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-1xvli5t r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1hdv0qi dots">
            <g>
              <circle cx="5" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
              <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
              <circle cx="19" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
            </g>
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="popup">
          <div class="popup-option">
            <div>
              <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="popup-icon">
                <g>
                  <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z"></path>
                  <path d="M12 13.415c1.892 0 3.633.95 4.656 2.544.224.348.123.81-.226 1.035-.348.226-.812.124-1.036-.226-.747-1.162-2.016-1.855-3.395-1.855s-2.648.693-3.396 1.854c-.224.35-.688.45-1.036.225-.35-.224-.45-.688-.226-1.036 1.025-1.594 2.766-2.545 4.658-2.545zm4.216-3.957c0 .816-.662 1.478-1.478 1.478s-1.478-.66-1.478-1.478c0-.817.662-1.478 1.478-1.478s1.478.66 1.478 1.478zm-5.476 0c0 .816-.662 1.478-1.478 1.478s-1.478-.66-1.478-1.478c0-.817.662-1.478 1.478-1.478.817 0 1.478.66 1.478 1.478z"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <p>Not interested in this tweet</p>
          </div>
          <div class="popup-option">
            <div>
              <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="popup-icon">
                <g>
                  <path d="M20.083 6.173l2.323 2.323c.293.293.768.293 1.06 0s.294-.768 0-1.06l-2.32-2.326 2.322-2.323c.293-.294.293-.77 0-1.062s-.768-.293-1.06 0L20.082 4.05 17.76 1.73c-.293-.293-.768-.293-1.06 0-.147.146-.22.338-.22.53s.072.384.22.53l2.32 2.32-2.32 2.325c-.147.146-.22.338-.22.53s.072.384.22.53c.292.293.767.293 1.06 0l2.323-2.32zM8.417 11.816c1.355 0 2.872-.15 3.84-1.256.813-.93 1.077-2.367.806-4.392-.38-2.826-2.116-4.513-4.645-4.513-2.53 0-4.267 1.687-4.646 4.513-.273 2.025-.01 3.462.805 4.393.968 1.108 2.485 1.257 3.84 1.257zm-3.16-5.448c.16-1.2.786-3.212 3.16-3.212 2.373 0 2.998 2.013 3.16 3.212.207 1.55.056 2.627-.45 3.205-.455.52-1.266.743-2.71.743s-2.256-.223-2.71-.743c-.507-.578-.658-1.656-.45-3.205zm11.44 12.867c-.88-3.525-4.283-5.988-8.28-5.988-3.998 0-7.403 2.463-8.28 5.988-.172.693-.03 1.4.395 1.94.408.522 1.04.822 1.733.822H14.57c.69 0 1.323-.3 1.73-.82.425-.54.568-1.247.396-1.942zm-1.577 1.018c-.126.16-.316.245-.55.245H2.264c-.235 0-.426-.085-.552-.246-.137-.174-.18-.412-.12-.654.71-2.855 3.517-4.85 6.824-4.85s6.113 1.994 6.824 4.85c.06.24.017.48-.12.655z"></path>
                </g>
              </svg>
            </div>
            <p>Unfollow whoever</p>
          </div>

          <div class="popup-option">
            <div>
              <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="popup-icon">
                <g>
                  <path d="M1.75 22.354c-.192 0-.384-.073-.53-.22-.293-.293-.293-.768 0-1.06L20.395 1.898c.293-.294.768-.294 1.06 0s.294.767 0 1.06L2.28 22.135c-.146.146-.338.22-.53.22zm1.716-5.577c-.134 0-.27-.036-.392-.11-.67-.413-1.07-1.13-1.07-1.917v-5.5c0-1.24 1.01-2.25 2.25-2.25H6.74l7.047-5.588c.225-.18.533-.215.792-.087.258.125.423.387.423.675v3.28c0 .415-.336.75-.75.75s-.75-.335-.75-.75V3.553L7.47 8.338c-.134.104-.298.162-.467.162h-2.75c-.413 0-.75.337-.75.75v5.5c0 .263.134.5.356.64.353.216.462.678.245 1.03-.14.23-.387.357-.64.357zm10.787 5.973c-.166 0-.33-.055-.466-.162l-4.795-3.803c-.325-.258-.38-.73-.122-1.054.258-.322.73-.38 1.054-.12l3.58 2.838v-7.013c0-.414.335-.75.75-.75s.75.336.75.75V22c0 .288-.166.55-.425.675-.104.05-.216.075-.327.075z"></path>
                </g>
              </svg> </div>
            <p>Mute whoever</p>
          </div>
          <div class="popup-option">
            <div>
              <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="popup-icon">
                <g>
                  <path d="M12 1.25C6.072 1.25 1.25 6.072 1.25 12S6.072 22.75 12 22.75 22.75 17.928 22.75 12 17.928 1.25 12 1.25zm0 1.5c2.28 0 4.368.834 5.982 2.207L4.957 17.982C3.584 16.368 2.75 14.282 2.75 12c0-5.1 4.15-9.25 9.25-9.25zm0 18.5c-2.28 0-4.368-.834-5.982-2.207L19.043 6.018c1.373 1.614 2.207 3.7 2.207 5.982 0 5.1-4.15 9.25-9.25 9.25z"></path>
                </g>
              </svg>
            </div>
            <p>Block whoever</p>
          </div>
          <div class="popup-option">
            <div>
              <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="popup-icon">
                <g>
                  <path d="M20.083 6.173l2.323 2.323c.293.293.768.293 1.06 0s.294-.768 0-1.06l-2.32-2.326 2.322-2.323c.293-.294.293-.77 0-1.062s-.768-.293-1.06 0L20.082 4.05 17.76 1.73c-.293-.293-.768-.293-1.06 0-.147.146-.22.338-.22.53s.072.384.22.53l2.32 2.32-2.32 2.325c-.147.146-.22.338-.22.53s.072.384.22.53c.292.293.767.293 1.06 0l2.323-2.32zM8.417 11.816c1.355 0 2.872-.15 3.84-1.256.813-.93 1.077-2.367.806-4.392-.38-2.826-2.116-4.513-4.645-4.513-2.53 0-4.267 1.687-4.646 4.513-.273 2.025-.01 3.462.805 4.393.968 1.108 2.485 1.257 3.84 1.257zm-3.16-5.448c.16-1.2.786-3.212 3.16-3.212 2.373 0 2.998 2.013 3.16 3.212.207 1.55.056 2.627-.45 3.205-.455.52-1.266.743-2.71.743s-2.256-.223-2.71-.743c-.507-.578-.658-1.656-.45-3.205zm11.44 12.867c-.88-3.525-4.283-5.988-8.28-5.988-3.998 0-7.403 2.463-8.28 5.988-.172.693-.03 1.4.395 1.94.408.522 1.04.822 1.733.822H14.57c.69 0 1.323-.3 1.73-.82.425-.54.568-1.247.396-1.942zm-1.577 1.018c-.126.16-.316.245-.55.245H2.264c-.235 0-.426-.085-.552-.246-.137-.174-.18-.412-.12-.654.71-2.855 3.517-4.85 6.824-4.85s6.113 1.994 6.824 4.85c.06.24.017.48-.12.655z"></path>
                </g>
              </svg>
            </div>
            <p>Mark as spoiler</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```